# Apache POI: Unable to replace text in .docx template

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to replace some text in my .docx template using Java, `Apache POI`. I am using the latest version of Apache POI. Below is my code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class POIDocWriter
{
    public void createClientInitialLetter(String input, String output, String clientName, String address, String date) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException
    {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("Invoice.docx"));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                String text = r.getText(0);

                System.out.println(text);
                if (text.contains("#ADDRESS#")) 
                {
                    text = text.replace("#ADDRESS#", address);

                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

                if (text.contains("#DATE#")) 
                {
                    text = text.replace("#DATE#", date);

                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

                if (text.contains("#DATE#")) 
                {
                    text = text.replace("#DATE#", date);

                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

                if (text.contains("#CLIENTNAME#")) 
                {
                    text = text.replace("#CLIENTNAME#", "Johan");

                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

            }


         }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream("output.docx"));


    }

}
```

My .docx template can be found in below dropbox link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/luiws9pz9q3whe5/Invoice.docx?dl=0

My issue is, I have am only getting the below error and nothing is happening to the template.

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at POIDocWriter.createClientInitialLetter(POIDocWriter.java:30)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

My code works fine with templates which do not have images and table, so I think this is something about images and tables. How can I replace the text in my `.docx` template and save it as a new document using `Apache POI`?

**Update**

Problem here is not exactly the NULL check. Even with NULL Check, it do not replace the values. If I do the NULL check, there are no errors anyway and the below output is displayed in console. As you can see, it "breaked" the text in my document, so it could not find the word I am seeking for.

Apart from that, it is not replacing any value inside the table!!!

```
Advance Payment
#
NAME
#
#
ADDRESS
#
#DATE
#
Vat Payable: #VAT#
Signature
```

Comment: Which line is line 30 i´n `POIDocWriter`?

Comment: @Jens: Hi. Line 30 is `if (text.contains("#ADDRESS#")) `

Comment: So it looks line `r.getText(0);` return null.

Comment: @Jens: I don't think that is a helpful answer...

Comment: The [XWPFRun javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#getText%28int%29) clearly state that a call to getText can return null if there's no text there, any reason given that why you're not doing the null check that Jens is suggesting?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @Gagravarr: Apart from that, it is not replacing any value inside the table!!!

Comment: Microsoft Word is well known for needlessly breaking text up into multiple runs, even when they share the same formatting. (The file format requires that a new run be used whenever formatting changes). What happens if you update your logic to cope with text potentially spanning multiple ranges?

Comment: Try to use `p.getTex()` so you get the text of the paragraph.

Comment: i have use same code as above but it gives me following error.                                                                                                      The method getRuns() is undefined for the type XWPFParagraph

Comment: @PeakGen Have you found a solution for this? I am also facing a same type of issue